# How can I print items in an array in numerical order?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I have a for loop that pushes items into an array if they pass a certain condition. I then output each item of its respective array so that it's displayed in an iteration in a table structure:

```
var row = "";
var CatNum = [];
var Org = [];
var tooltip = {
                cat1: '',
                cat2: ''
            };
```

for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i].catType === 'I')
                {
                    CatNum.push(data[i].catNum);
                    Org.push(data[i].org);
                    trackingNumber.push(data[i].trackingNumber)

                    row = '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="tooltip-Val">' + <NUMERICAL ORDER HERE:> +  Org[i] + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                    tooltip.cat1 = tooltip.cat1.concat(row);
                }

                else if (data[i].catType === 'II')
                {
                    CatNum.push(data[i].catNum);
                    Org.push(data[i].org);
                    trackingNumber.push(data[i].trackingNumber);

                    row = '<tr>' +
                        '<td class="tooltip-Val">' + <NUMERICAL ORDER HERE:> +  Org[i] + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>';

                    tooltip.cat2 = tooltip.cat2.concat(row);
                }
```

What I'd like to do is order each iteration in numerical order.

Right now i don't have a method for numbering each loop that gets printed.
My goal is to have the HTML print like so:

```
CATI :
   1. xxxxx

   2. xxxxx

   3. xxxxx

CATII :
   1. yyyyy

   2. yyyyy
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: You can create a variable that is incremented only when `if` condition is `true`

Comment: not sure I follow, care to provide your though process in the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment variables initially set to `0` if `if` or `else if` condition is `true`

```
for (var i = 0, cat 1 = 0, cat2 = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i].catType === 'I') {
    CatNum.push(data[i].catNum);
    Org.push(data[i].org);
    trackingNumber.push(data[i].trackingNumber)

    row = '<tr>' 
      // increment `cat1`
      + '<td class="tooltip-Val">' + (++cat1) + Org[i] + '</td>'
      + '</tr>';

    tooltip.cat1 = tooltip.cat1.concat(row);
  } else if (data[i].catType === 'II') {
    CatNum.push(data[i].catNum);
    Org.push(data[i].org);
    trackingNumber.push(data[i].trackingNumber);
    // increment `cat2`
    row = '<tr>' + '<td class="tooltip-Val">' + (++cat2) + Org[i] 
      + '</td>' 
      + '</tr>';

    tooltip.cat2 = tooltip.cat2.concat(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo _"why not use the array length of cat1 and cat2 respectively increasing by one, insted of two new variables incrementing?"_ What do you mean by "use the array length of cat1 and cat2"?

Comment: My bad, I thought that tooltip.cat1 and tooltip.cat2 were arrays.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo _"I thought that tooltip.cat1 and tooltip.cat2 were arrays"_ They could be, though that portion of `js` is not part of actual Question _"What I'd like to do is order each iteration in numerical order."_

Answer (score 0):

Just add two variables to keep track of the counts like

```
var indexOne = 1, indextwo = 1;   
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ...
```

and replace `<NUMERICAL ORDER HERE:>` with `indexOne++` and `indextwo++` respectively.